# avoiding csrf error in django 1.4.3

Tags: python, django, templates, view, csrf

I am using django to design a basic login and logout page. so below are my code

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...........
    ...........
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.csrf",
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    .......
    ....... 
)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
             url(r'^$', 'learn_django.views.home_page'),          
             url(r'^login/$', 'learn_django.views.login'),
             url(r'^logged_in$', 'learn_django.views.logged_in'),
             url(r'^logout/$', 'learn_django.views.logout'),
)


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
) + urlpatterns
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def home_page(request):
    return render_to_response("home_page.html")

def login(request):
    return render_to_response("login.html")

def logged_in(request):
    return render_to_response("logged_in.html",context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home_remaining.css' %}" type="text/css">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <header>
     <div class='header_div'>
       <div class="logout"><p id='logout'><a href="/logout" >Logout</a></p><div>
       <div class="login"><p id='login'> <a href="/login" >Login</a></p><div>
     </div>
   </header>
   <div class="body_content">
      {% block body %}{% endblock %}
   </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Login Page{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  <div id='container'>
      <form action="/logged_in" method="POST">
         {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="name">Username:</label><input type="name">
            <label for="username">Password:</label><input type="password">
            <div id="lower">
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </div>
      </form> 
   </div>     
{% endblock %}
```

So above is my complet code that displays a login form when we click on `Login` link given in `base.html`.

After login has displayed and entered some `username` and `password` and clicked `Login` button , a error page that indicates `csrf error` has been displayed

Googled a lot and added `{% csrf_token %}` inside the form tags , also added `django.core.context_processors.csrf` in the template context process in `settings.py`

So below is the error message something looks like

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF cookie not set.

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.
You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

So when i removed the django.core.context_processors.csrf from the template context process its working fine. But i want to use also csrf protection.

Finally and actually whats wrong in the above view code and why the csrf error page is appearing and how to avoid the above error page ?

whether i need to add any code in my `views.py` functions ?

Can any one please add the basic login and logout functionality code in my above functions so that it will be more helpful to understand the code practically......

### Edited

For the above problem i imported csrf_exempt function like below

`from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

and given this as a decorator before the `logged_in` view  and it worked no error page displaying when i clicked login button

But still wondering why the below mentioned methods like sending the Requestcontext from templates is not working

Comment: decorating the view with csrf_exempt just removes the csrf protection. I can't think that it will effect your csrf issue, but your login and logged_in views should be combined into one view. See - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass a `RequestContext` to your `render_to_response` function.

```
def home_page(request):
    return render_to_response("home_page.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Either that or use the new render function, which handles passing the `RequestContext` for you.

```
def home_page(request):
    return render(request, "home_page.html")
```

The RequestContext adds various useful things to the context dictionary that is passed to the template. This includes the csrf token. Have a look at the [RequestContext docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) for more info.

In your case your `login` view is rendering the `login.html` template, but not passing the csrf token. When the `login.html` template posts back to the server (to `/logged_in`), the `logged_in` view checks for that csrf token. It's not there (because you never included it). so it assumes it's received a cross site request forgery.

Have a read of the [csrf docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/) to make more sense of the process.

Comment: You still need to pass `request` to `render()`.

Comment: Actually the problem is not when i accessed the home page,it is when i clicked on the login button which sends the request to logged_in view function in which i have already sent the Requestcontext as you can see above right ?

Comment: You need to pass a RequestContext to all your render_to_response functions (or at least those in views whose template will return post data to your server). Copy the pattern I've shown above to your login view.

Comment: Your login view is rendering the login.html template, but not passing the csrf token. When the login.html template posts back to the server (to /logged_in), the logged_in view checks for that csrf token. It's not there (because you never included it). so it assumes it's received a cross site request forgery.

Comment: yeah i had tried by copying the Requestcontext to all the view functions when rendering and tried to click the login button and still its not working and showing same csrf error page

Comment: Is that Requestcontext or RequestContext? Also add a slash to the regex for your logged_in url, and make sure refresh the login page before testing the process.

Comment: Its a RequestContext itself, just a typo error here, its not working when sending it through template.k anyway i am confused from starting about django form handling is.... here in the above html file i have used pure html form code and not used django form classes, so how to access the form variables like username and password in the logged_in view function above ?

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/.